# Unable to perform get request using state as query parameter

Tags: reactjs, axios, state

[Full repo containing this component.](https://github.com/pedro-surf/test_component_laborit)
EDIT: 
state already gets updated(fixed) after I try using this GET request. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
getModels = async () => {
  this.setState({ loading: "Fetching models..." });
let brand = this.state.query_brand;
await axios.get(`https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/${brand}/modelos/`)
           .then(res => this.setState({ models: res.data }))
```

I made calls to this function on my onChangeHandler functions successfully .

```
  onChangeHandler = async (e) => {
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value, target: e.target.name });
  this.getModels();
};
```

I know the onchangehandler is hardcoded since it's now only handling one specific change (when I want to request models), but I'd like to focus on the main problem. Thanks in advance! Best regards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Pedro! Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks Tholle! What's missing? every other part of this code is working finely, just this state update with axios request is broken.. edit: it doesn't show me any errors, just doesn't update state as desired

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly what might be wrong unless there is some piece of runnable code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: here is the full component: https://github.com/pedro-surf/ufsc_exercises/blob/master/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j2n9p5o813) and an error is raised line 27 in your code, I guess that is the reason of your problem :

`let brand = this.state.query_brand.toNumber();`

The method `toNumber` does not exist. You can use the method `Number`
ex: `var stringToInteger = Number('10')`.

A article on the topic [here](https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/)

Comment: Actually, I get a 404 error on this address : `https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/${brand}/modelos/` (with the variable brand having a value of course).
I guess it's wrongly formatted. You should check it out ;)